# How to cbind objects from the.GlobalEnv with certain string pattern?

Tags: r

I have a bunch of objects in my Environment and I would like to `cbind` them into a data frame based on some string pattern. For Example:

```
A.LLB<-c(1,2,3,4)
A.LBW<-c(2,3,4,5)
A.L2B<-c(5,33,6,7)
A.F2G<-c(5,33,6,7)
```

I would like to bind `A.LLB` and `A.L2B` and `F2G` only. I tried the following:

```
obj.list <- eapply(.GlobalEnv,function(x) if(is.vector(x)) x)

Test<-as.data.frame(do.call(cbind, obj.list))
```

which binds all objects together. So I added:

```
obj.list <- eapply(.GlobalEnv,function(x) if(is.vector(x)) x & grepl('LLB','L2B', 'F2G'))
```

But thats seems wrong.

Comment: Seems like you could use `do.call(cbind, lapply(ls(pattern = "L(L|2)B"), get))`

Comment: Or `data.frame(mget(ls(pattern= 'L(L|2)B')))`  If you are using `data.table` `setDT(mget(ls(pattern= 'L(L|2)B')))[]`

Comment: I just added `F2G`. I hope that doesnt change the Syntax. Thank you!

Comment: YOu may need to change the `pattern` to include the new object i..e `ls(pattern= '(F|L)(L|2)(B|G)')`

Comment: Do you need all those in your environment? Is it possible to put them in a list while creating them?

Comment: @RichardScriven You could post that as a solution as I just modified your modified slightly.